# Streaming a Video on raspberry to rtsp in specified resolution

Tags: linux, video, raspberry-pi

I am currently using this command:

```
libcamera-vid -t 0 --inline --framerate 30 -o - | cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream1}' :demux=h264
```

Even though the sensor has a resolution of 2592 x 1944, the driver seems to only set it to a resolution of 640 x 480
(output:)

```
libcamera-vid -t 0 --inline --framerate 30 -o - | cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream1}' :demux=h264
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 1.0.6-1682-g88158c836)
[014c4010] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[01439b98] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[014c4010] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
Preview window unavailable
[11:10:08.908820944] [11839]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3406-e96d0201
[11:10:08.931110987] [11846] ERROR CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:551 'ov5647 10-0036': Camera sensor does not support test pattern modes.
[11:10:08.954015489] [11846]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1326 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[11:10:08.954716951] [11839]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-YUV420
[11:10:08.955574644] [11846]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:747 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 640x480-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 640x480-pGAA
[11:10:08.983201335] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: Saturation = 1.000000
[11:10:08.983283728] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: Contrast = 1.000000
[11:10:08.983323397] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: Brightness = 0.000000
[11:10:08.983359065] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: AwbMode = 0
[11:10:08.983392715] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: Sharpness = 1.000000
[11:10:08.983428310] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: ExposureValue = 0.000000
[11:10:08.983463349] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: AeExposureMode = 0
[11:10:08.983494109] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: FrameDurationLimits = [ 33333, 33333 ]
[11:10:08.983530315] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: AeMeteringMode = 0
[11:10:08.983562150] [11859]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:626 Request ctrl: NoiseReductionMode = 1
[a2603578] main stream error: unknown query 0x30e in demux_vaControlHelper
```

The video feed looks spotless.
On the other hand...
When I use the command

```
libcamera-vid -t 0 --inline --framerate 30 -o - --width 1920 --height 1080 | cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream1}' :demux=h264
```

I can only see a fraction of the original viewangle. How can I say the camera otherwise to use 1080p30?

Comment: You need to clarify your question so that others can answer it. Please include the used OS version as well as example images of the issue

Answer (score 0):

You might yet have an answer on this after two months, but this question frequently occurs.

Camera picture is cropped according to resolution (and therefore ratio) set.

Try 1280x960 and you'll see most of your angle.

There's a single (!) image with information about video modes on one of the hardware sites. Shows a picture with boxes according to resolutions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).